# No such file or directory when using cat command with hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, command-line, terminal

I have two files within a directory, one called word_mapper.py and another called README.md. I am trying to use these files with hadoop, but when I run the command `hadoop fs -cat README.md | python3 word_mapper.py` i get the following response from my terminal:

```
2021-02-12 14:13:55,862 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
cat: `README.md': No such file or directory
```

Hadoop is up and running so not exactly sure how to get about fixing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try supplying the absolute/full path? the hadoop command might be looking relative to the wrong location.

Comment: @PinggerShikkoken unfortunately that didn't change much. I tried to relocate the files, also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop fs` commands default to read from your HDFS user folder.

You would need to first `hadoop fs -put README.md`, or if you meant to `cat` a local file (as you said you have "*two files within a directory, one called word_mapper.py and another called README.md*"), then remove `hadoop fs -` from your command because your local directory where the files are located and the Python code is running, are not HDFS

If you actually want to use Python to run a mapper, then I suggest looking at `mrjob`, but probably better off using PySpark since MapReduce isn't widely used